# How to choose one from all matches? C# AForge

Tags: c#, .net, image-recognition, aforge

I am doing image recognition with c# and AForge and i get few matches which is great becouse there is few identical things in picture. But how do i choose a single one of them? I need to somehow change `foreach(){}` here is my code:

```
ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching( 0.925f );
// find all matchings with specified above similarity
TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage( sourceImage, template );
// highlight found matchings
BitmapData data = sourceImage.LockBits(
    new Rectangle( 0, 0, sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height ),
    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, sourceImage.PixelFormat );
foreach ( TemplateMatch m in matchings ) // <-----how to change this to select only one random thing?
{
    Drawing.Rectangle( data, m.Rectangle, Color.White );
    // do something else with matching
}
sourceImage.UnlockBits( data );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with a concrete array of matches, not a `linq` enumerable that may trigger some long-winded evaluation, it seems you need something along these lines:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var rndPick = matches[rnd.Next(matches.Length)];
```

**Example - a linqpad snipped**

```
string[] matches = new string[] {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"};

Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    matches[rnd.Next(matches.Length)].Dump();
```

**Non LinqPad, just write the selected item to the console**

```
 for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
      Console.Writeline(matches[rnd.Next(matches.Length)]);
```

Comment: I am trying to use your example but i am new to programming what is that `Dump()` ?

Comment: [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) is a nice C# tool. `Dump` is an extension method that emits the content of the LHS item to the console. You can just as directly write the answer to the Console (updated example)